# Can a diode reverse leakage current cause error in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, diodes, leakage-current

I want to measure C2 leakage current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvS9VE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 has a leakage current of its own, to prevent C1 leakage current cause error in the leakage readings of C2 I put a diode in series but the diode have a reverse leakage current itself.

- How do I prevent C1 leakage current affecting the C2 leakage current readings?

Comment: The leakage of C1 will make the voltage across C1 drop when it is not being charged. However C1 is constantly charged through the bridge rectifier! So the drop in voltage across C1 due to leakage of C1 will be negligable. I do not think there is any issue.

Comment: Are you able to add a mechanical switch after the diode?  That way you could allow the circuit to fully charge, then open the switch, the only leakage of C2 will then be through AM1.

Comment: @Nedd When the switch you suggest is opened, what will the current meter AM1 show? How would OP measure any leakage current?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie What if I use mylar capacitor? X10 1uF (10uF)? I've heard they've very low down to nothing leakage current?

Comment: *What if I use mylar capacitor? X10 1uF?* For C1 or C2? To solve what issue? I explained that the leakage of C1 **is not an issue** so why does this non-issue need to be solved?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie For C1 only, you're right I wasn't listening, thanks.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie So should I ditch the diode too?

Comment: *So should I ditch the diode too?* Yes I would remove it, it isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as BR1 can provide a much higher current than the leakage current of C1 and C2 together I would not expect a potential difference between C2 and C1. Since there is no real load, DC Voltage will be AC peak voltage minus voltage drop at BR1. (approx. 635V) Ripple should be low for the same reason.

You could use a ripple suppressor instead of D1 if you want to stabilize voltage at C2. This would give you a small but defined voltage drop from the filter capacitor to your device under test.

[image: ripple suppression]

\$C_1\$ is the filter capacitor you already have.

\$R_1\$ and \$C_2\$ will make ripple imperceptible.

\$R_2\$ is a minimal load that will keep the circuit from floating.

If you prefer MOSFETs a circuit like the following might do, but I have not tested it myself.

[image]

Comment: Can I use a MOSFET instead of a BJT, will it have the same effect of "ripple suppression"?

Comment: R1 and C2  are a low-pass filter. If the BJT is replaced by a MOSFET no charge can get out of C2. No, it would not work.  MOSFETs would need a different circuitry.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about that different circuitry, I know it's unrelated to the question but I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Please do not forget to add a fuse. Use a isolation transformer. Make sure that your equipment has the security rating for this relatively high voltage.

Comment: Thanks, I have to say; as your first answer, it was well written and explained. welcome to EE.SE.